# CakePHP: to many belongsTo associations contained leads to DB running into JOIN limit

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

We are currently on CakePHP 3.7.5, using MariaDB as our database engine (10.4.12 on dev, 10.2, 10.2 on client machines).

Some of our table classes have a lot of belongsTo associations. Many of them pointing to a contacts table, but even more to an options table. We use this table to store arbitrary values for different properties of models so that the clients can manage these lists themselves, add entries or change their textual representation while keeping the referenced id.

**Main Table: entities**

```
id INT(11)
name VARCHAR(256)
administrator_contact_id INT(11)
account_manager_contact_id INT(11)
property_manager_contact_id INT(11)
...
type_id INT(11)
classification_id INT(11)
status_id INT(11)
category_id INT(11)
...
```

**contacts table**

```
id INT(11)
first_name VARCHAR(256)
last_name VARCHAR(256)
```

**options table**

```
id INT(11)
name VARCHAR(256)
```

**EntitiesTable class**

```
class EntitiesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->addAssociations([
            'belongsTo' => [
                'AdministratorContact' => [
                    'className' => 'Contacts',
                ],
                'AccountManagerContact' => [
                    'className' => 'Contacts',
                ],
                'PropertyManagerContact' => [
                    'className' => 'Contacts',
                ],
                ...
                'Type' => [
                    'className' => 'Options',
                ],
                'Classification' => [
                    'className' => 'Options',
                ],
                'Status' => [
                    'className' => 'Options',
                ],
                'Category' => [
                    'className' => 'Options',
                ],
                ...
            ],
            ...
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Example query in a Controller**

```
$this->loadModel('Entities');
$query = $this->Entities->find('all', [
    'conditions' => [
        ...
    ],
    'contain' => [
        'AdministratorContact',
        'AccountManagerContact',
        'PropertyManagerContact',
        ...
        'Type',
        'Classification',
        'Status',
        'Category',
        ....
    ],
]);
$results = $query->toArray();
```

Now, for the first time, we ran into MariaDBs limit of 61 JOINs. Our belongsTo associations are added using the default "join" strategy as it reduces the overall number of queries that have to be executed for serving a single request. Changing the strategy of all belongsTo associations to "select" would lead to way too many, unnecessary separate queries.

I was wondering if anybody heard of best practises, or whether there is a behavior that caters to this need. Things that come to my mind:

- Before running a query, analyse how many associations are contained which would lead to JOINs, plus anything else that would lead to additional JOINs ("join" clause in the query, LinkableBehavior). If it exceeds the limit, turn some of them into separate SELECTs by amending their "strategy".
- Somehow aggregate JOINS coming form belongsTo associations pointing to the same table by collecting the ids, and after the query has run "distribute" the results. Kind of what is done for hasMany associations, but there the results are turned into entities which are then all added as **one** property (containing an array of results), whereas for belongsTo we would then need to distribute the results back to different properties of the main model.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly that you are currently joining one and the same table (presumably a key-value store) multiple times (presumably with conditions) to poupulate different properties?

Comment: Yes, a key-value store is one use case, but also a contacts table, as pointed out below. We have different responsibilities for e.g. company records, each of them defined as a belongsTo association, but all of them pointing to the contacts table.

Comment: I have no idea what exactly the deal is with the contact table, ie how it's different to what you're doing with the options table, it's all very vague, but surely it's possible to achieve what you want, result formatters, custom associations/eager-loaders, etc., but in order to come up with a fitting suggestion, or even some implementation specifics, a little more info as to how exactly your associations are being set up, and maybe what the schema of the involved tables look like would be very helpful.

Comment: I added some exemplary code. It is not about the tables, their aspects, it is about the basic principle of belongsTo associations being turned into JOINs, too many of which leading to problems, if the database again does not support that.